# android kotlin lambda to add two integers

Tags: android, lambda, kotlin

We are trying to use a lambda expression in android with Kotlin to add two integers. We have looked at the docs. Made our syntax verbatim to the docs. Here is the output that is set in a EditText field.

```
Function2<java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer, java.lang.Integer>
```

Our code is implemented with a onClick event of a button. Code Below

```
val x:Int = 5
val y:Int = 17
// Set at top level
fun onINHRclass(view: View){

    val sumB = {x:Int,y:Int -> x + y}
    println("======================"+sumB)
    etANSpg2.setText(sumB.toString())
}
```

The question is how to use a lambda to add two integers and set the result in a EditText field?

We have looked at and tried variations of other posts and other tutorials
the lambda works on the website Try Kotlin but it does not have a EditText field

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The question is how to use a lambda to add two integers and set the
>   result in a EditText field?

`sumB` is like a function, so you should call it like a function:

```
val x:Int = 5
val y:Int = 17
// Set at top level
fun onINHRclass(view: View){

    val sumB = {x:Int,y:Int -> x + y}
    println("======================"+sumB)
    etANSpg2.setText(sumB(x, y).toString())
}
```

Comment: How does one know that sumB is like a function. I tested and it works but where did you learn that ? Other than the fact that your a pro at this ! You have bailed me out twice now THX

Comment: [kotlin doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#invoking-a-function-type-instance) is your best friend:)